# How to simulate user intercation in Django?

Tags: django, automation, simulation

I have a Django project representing an abstract retail store. Let's say it's deployed on a server and is available in the local network. I want to write another program (or extend this one?) to generate a bunch of Users, automate the process of signing up and logging in and automate their interaction with the system: make them interact with the system to order goods. So it's not just unit testing of my system but rather demonstration of how it works in real life. And I want to spawn many users to see how my system can handle many requests at once.
Is there some kind of framework for that? How would you implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of software available for this specific need.

https://jmeter.apache.org/
https://www.cypress.io/
[https://www.browserstack.com/selenium#:~:text=Selenium%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,%2C%20and%20C%23%2C%20among%20others](https://www.browserstack.com/selenium#:%7E:text=Selenium%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,%2C%20and%20C%23%2C%20among%20others).

Go through these, hope you will find your solution